# keep the text format when i parse with xml a text from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing, text-formatting

I have a google maps app in javascript with markers that when you click in them, a text stored in a mysql database is displayed in the a DIV tag like in this video: https://youtu.be/VtcxLoAG7Wk

The problem is that that text is displayed without breaklines when it has them. Even in the database as you can see in the video, the text stored still have the format.

So my question is how to display this text keeping the text format, as you can see in the code i used from google maps it is done with parsing xml.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

var name;
var html;
var type;
var lat;
var point;


    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1351, 11.5820),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> </text> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,

          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, name);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, name, downloadUrl) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        // infoWindow.setContent(html);
        // infoWindow.open(map, marker);

       var textillo = document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = name;
      });
    }
```

then the main function that display the markers in the map calls another code:

```
<?php
require("dbinfo.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $user, $pass);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';


?>
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions. They were deprecated in PHP 5.5, which is so old it no longer even receives security updates, and completely removed in PHP 7, which was released in December, 2015. Instead, use PDO (or `mysqli_*` if you must).

Comment: Can you provide example inputs, actual outputs, and expected outputs?

Answer (score 0):

To just "keep" the newlines, you can convert the newlines from your database to br-tags in HTML, with the [nl2br PHP function](http://php.net/nl2br).

Like so:

```
<?php
$yourText = 'text gotten from
database';
echo nl2br($yourText);
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.
If i put like this: 
var textillo = document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML =nl2br(name); it doesn't display anything
and if i put it like this:
var name = nl2br(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
the marker are not even set in the map.

I don't know why this happens

Comment: That looks a lot like you are trying to use the nl2br() php-function inside of JavaScript. This can not work, since it is a PHP function. I think you should be good when you change your parseToXml function to return like this: `return nl2br($xmlStr);`

Comment: I just tried in this piece of code as you said, but it doesn't work, when i do it, the markers don't populate the map.



function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return nl2br($xmlStr);
}

is it here where you meant to add the nl2br?

Comment: now i put in this place.

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
echo 'name="' . parseToXML(nl2br($row['name'])) . '" ';

and what it was before like this:

hello world. I would lke to display like this jewkje`fj dljg´klerj

no it is like this:
hello world.<br /> I would lke to display like this<br /> jewkje`fj<br /> dljg´klerj

the problem is that it doesn't understand that it is html, it just display the content of the database raw
any idea what is happening?